# Error inflating class com.facebook.ads.MediaView

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-audience-network

I've integrated Facebook Audience Network on my Android app for a while and so far I have no received any problem with it.

Recently I've updated the Facebook API Call from v2.5 to v3.0 and I've started to get these reports on my Crashlytic. It's working before but not anymore after the update. I can try reverting back to v2.5 and see if the situation improves but I'm just putting this here in hope other people have faced similar issue can offer some answers for this.

```
private void processLoadedAd(final NativeAd nativeAd) {
    nativeAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onError(Ad ad, AdError adError) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded(Ad ad) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onAdLoaded: " + ad);
            if (nativeAd != null) {
                nativeAd.unregisterView();
            }

            arrayNativeAd.add(nativeAd);
            adapterBulletinsRecommended.notifyDataSetChanged();
            rlRecommended.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdClicked(Ad ad) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onLoggingImpression(Ad ad) {

        }
    });
    nativeAd.loadAd();
}
```

---

```
 // Display our text and image at the specified position in the list
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
        final NativeAd nativeAd = nativeAds.get(position);
        viewHolder.itemView.setTag(nativeAd);

        viewHolder.mvAdPicture.setNativeAd(nativeAd);

        try {
            Glide.with(context)
                    .load(nativeAd.getAdIcon().getUrl())
                    .thumbnail(0.1f)
                    .dontAnimate()
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.RESULT)
                    .into(viewHolder.ivAdIcon);
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            Glide.with(context)
                    .load(nativeAd.getAdChoicesIcon().getUrl())
                    .thumbnail(0.1f)
                    .dontAnimate()
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.RESULT)
                    .into(viewHolder.ivAdChoicesIcon);
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        viewHolder.tvTitle.setText(nativeAd.getAdTitle());
        viewHolder.tvSocialContext.setText(nativeAd.getAdSocialContext());
        viewHolder.tvAdBody.setText(nativeAd.getAdBody());
        viewHolder.tvCTA.setText(nativeAd.getAdCallToAction());

        // Register the Title & CTA button to listen for clicks
        List<View> clickableViews = new ArrayList<>();
        clickableViews.add(viewHolder.tvTitle);
        clickableViews.add(viewHolder.tvCTA);
        nativeAd.registerViewForInteraction(viewHolder.cvContent, clickableViews);

        Log.i(TAG, "Title: " + nativeAd.getAdTitle());
        Log.i(TAG, "Description: " + nativeAd.getAdBody());
        Log.i(TAG, "Subtitle: " + nativeAd.getAdSubtitle());
        Log.i(TAG, "Image: " + nativeAd.getAdCoverImage().getUrl());
        Log.i(TAG, "Destination URL: " + nativeAd.getAdChoicesLinkUrl());
    }
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cv_content"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:elevation="20dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="10dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <com.facebook.ads.MediaView
                android:id="@+id/mv_ad_picture"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="155dp"
                android:background="@color/weak_tint_profile" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_adchoices_icon"
                android:layout_width="15dp"
                android:layout_height="15dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:background="@color/transparent" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_ad_icon"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/mv_ad_picture"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@color/transparent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@id/iv_ad_icon"
                android:layout_alignTop="@id/iv_ad_icon"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/iv_ad_icon">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/ll_ad_header"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/ll_cta"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_ad_title"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:ellipsize="end"
                        android:maxLines="2"
                        android:text="Ad Title"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_social_context"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:ellipsize="end"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:text="Social Context"
                        android:textColor="@color/secondary_text"
                        android:textSize="10sp" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/ll_cta"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/modern_btn_primary">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_cta"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                        android:paddingRight="10dp"
                        android:paddingTop="5dp"
                        android:text="CTA Button"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textSize="12sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </RelativeLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_ad_body"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/iv_ad_icon"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:text="Ad Body"
                android:textColor="@color/text_on_alpha"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

---

```
Fatal Exception: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Binary XML file line #19: Error inflating class com.facebook.ads.MediaView

Caused by android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Error inflating class com.facebook.ads.MediaView

Caused by java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Constructor.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:652)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:794)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:734)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:865)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:828)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:873)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:828)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:873)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:828)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:525)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:427)
       at worka.biz.worka.adapter.BulletinsRecommendedAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(Unknown Source)
       at worka.biz.worka.adapter.BulletinsRecommendedAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(Unknown Source)
       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(Unknown Source)
       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.clear(Unknown Source)
       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.clear(Unknown Source)
       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getScrapList(Unknown Source)
       at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.hasMore(Unknown Source)
       at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.generateDefaultLayoutParams(Unknown Source)
       at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.generateDefaultLayoutParams(Unknown Source)
       at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onSaveInstanceState(Unknown Source)
       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(Unknown Source)
       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(Unknown Source)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21121)
       at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:715)
       at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21121)
       at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:715)
       at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21121)
       at android.widget.ScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(ScrollView.java:2249)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
       at android.widget.ScrollView.onMeasure(ScrollView.java:543)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21121)
       at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:715)
       at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21121)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6462)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21121)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6462)
       at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.releaseTempRect(Unknown Source)
       at android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(Unknown Source)
       at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.layoutDependsOn(Unknown Source)
       at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(Unknown Source)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21121)
       at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(Unknown Source)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21121)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6462)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
       at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(Unknown Source)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21121)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6462)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:758)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:640)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21121)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6462)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21121)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6462)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:758)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:640)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21121)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6462)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
       at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:872)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21121)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2625)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1677)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1928)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1550)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7190)
       at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:959)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:734)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:670)
       at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:945)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1496)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1386)
Caused by java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: TextureView doesn't support displaying a background drawable
       at android.view.TextureView.setBackgroundDrawable(TextureView.java:315)
       at android.view.View.setBackground(View.java:19498)
       at android.view.View.(View.java)
       at android.view.View.(View.java)
       at android.view.View.(View.java)
       at android.view.TextureView.(TextureView.java)
       at com.facebook.ads.internal.view.d.c.b.(Unknown Source)
       at com.facebook.ads.internal.view.o.(Unknown Source)
       at com.facebook.ads.internal.view.j.(Unknown Source)
       at com.facebook.ads.MediaViewVideoRenderer.(Unknown Source)
       at com.facebook.ads.internal.view.h.(Unknown Source)
       at com.facebook.ads.MediaView.(Unknown Source)
       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Constructor.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:652)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:794)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:734)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:865)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:828)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:873)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:828)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:873)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:828)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:525)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:427)
       at worka.biz.worka.adapter.BulletinsRecommendedAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(Unknown Source)
       at worka.biz.worka.adapter.BulletinsRecommendedAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(Unknown Source)
       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(Unknown Source)
       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.clear(Unknown Source)
       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.clear(Unknown Source)
       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getScrapList(Unknown Source)
       at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.hasMore(Unknown Source)
       at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.generateDefaultLayoutParams(Unknown Source)
       at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.generateDefaultLayoutParams(Unknown Source)
       at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onSaveInstanceState(Unknown Source)
       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(Unknown Source)
       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(Unknown Source)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21121)
       at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:715)
       at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21121)
       at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:715)
       at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21121)
       at android.widget.ScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(ScrollView.java:2249)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
       at android.widget.ScrollView.onMeasure(ScrollView.java:543)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21121)
       at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:715)
       at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21121)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6462)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21121)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6462)
       at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.releaseTempRect(Unknown Source)
       at android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(Unknown Source)
       at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.layoutDependsOn(Unknown Source)
       at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(Unknown Source)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21121)
       at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(Unknown Source)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21121)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6462)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
       at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(Unknown Source)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21121)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6462)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:758)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:640)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21121)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6462)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21121)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6462)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:758)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:640)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21121)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6462)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
       at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:872)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21121)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2625)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1677)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1928)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1550)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7190)
       at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:959)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:734)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:670)
       at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:945)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1496)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1386)
```

Comment: Did you also change your `targetSdkVersion`? Because `TextureView doesn't support displaying a background drawable` error which is the root of your problem appears on Android N (api 24)

Comment: @pleft Following the error, I've updated the targetSdkVersion to 26 from 25... and along with the other lines affected on the gradle file to reflect the newest revision available on Google. But yes the only devices to be affected by this is on API 24 at the moment.

Comment: Hi, im facing the similar issue on xiaomi devices. did you get any solution regarding this issue ?

Comment: @Sarun1001 Unfortunately I only catch the exception for now just to get the newer devices crash-free.

Comment: @Reynolds R. G. G Now I face no issue when downgraded to Facebook SDK version v.4.23.0, Maybe you should take a look

Comment: @Sarun1001 I can confirm it works on 23. Fail on 24, 25, 26, it may troubled with android.support dependency.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the issue,you must add

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:*.*.*'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:*.*.*'
```

It has nothing to do with the sdk version.

Comment: I had both of it. Still not working for sdk 4.23 above.